# harmonic series as product over primes

Tags: calculus, analysis

If we consider the harmonic series written as such $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{n} = \prod_{\substack{p\text{ prime}}} (1+\frac{1}p+\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^3}+…) \tag{1}\label{1} $$

I don’t understand how it can be written in this form
$$\prod_{\substack{p\text{ prime}}} \frac{1}{1−\frac{1}p} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

In the first infinite product (\ref{1}) we have a bunch of power of primes, which are needed to write all the possible integer as a product of primes, but these power of prime don’t seem to appear in (\ref{2}).

How do you get from (\ref{1}) to (\ref{2})?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p$ is prime, then $p \ge 2$, so $0 < 1/p < 1$. The rest follows from the expansion:

$$\frac1{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$$

which is valid for $|x| < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For any prime number like $p$, we have $$\frac1{1 - \frac1p} = 1 + \frac1p + (\frac1p)^2 +(\frac1p)^3+ \cdots$$